# Intel i7 vt-x (vmx) suddenly not available any more?

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I'm using virtual box on my Windows 10 desktop (i7 6700k 64MB). I use it since years and now suddenly I got the famous message "Couldn't start vt-x not available..."

Hence I did the usual:

1. Checked Windows Hyper-V. I deinstalled the feature.
2. Executed "bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off" several times to play it sagfe.

But after serveral reboots, it is still the same.

Hence I checked the HW with HWiNFO64. It says "vmx not available". Hence I did a test. I entered BIOS and disabled virtualization and checked again with HWiNFO64. Then it said "vmx available but disabled". Hence again into BIOS and enabled it again but HWiNFO64 still say "vmx not available".

Has anyone an idea what could lead to the problem? Is there any new Windows 10 feature which may occupy the virtualization on start up except Hyper-V?

Best regards,

Tom

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I found the problem. Windows 10 Defender feature "core isolation" was activated. This security feature uses virtualization to mitigate root kits etc. Hence virtual box was not able to start.

I deactivated the feature by registry hack. Virtualbox works fine again.